# Can I recover my data after accidental factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery

My phone just managed to do a factory reset, all on its own. Can I somehow retrieve at least the portion of the lost data? On computer for both linux and windows there are programs that can recover parts of harddrive which have been marked empty but still contain data from deleted files.

Is there a way to do this on Samsung Galaxy with Android 4.1.2? Because I really need my contacts and some of my memo notes were really important.

Comment: Have a loot at Questions/Answer under the [tag:data-recovery] tag. I'm sure you'll see something useful in there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all of the data mentioned by you is stored in the cloud. Except your pics unless you have uploaded them via picasa etc.

Comment: It says sync error. Either google is broken or my phone is. Either way, I don't actually remember syncing anything...